# Descending Linked list nodes insertion

Tags: java, linked-list, iteration

I have the following code for inserting nodes. However, it inserts them in ascending order:

```
public void add(T item, int priority) throws QueueOverflowException {    
    SortedLinkedListNode<T> current = head;
    SortedLinkedListNode<T> previous = new SortedLinkedListNode<T>(); 
    SortedLinkedListNode<T> newNode = new SortedLinkedListNode<T>(); 
    newNode.priority = priority;
    newNode.data = item; 
    previous =null;

    while (current != null && current.priority <= priority) {
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }

    if (previous == null) {
        newNode.next = current;
        first = newNode;
    } else {
        newNode.next = current;
        previous.next = newNode;
    }
}
```

However I would need to insert it in descending order, any pointers on how to achieve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: The logic for determining order is `current.priority <= priority`. That's your starting point :-)

Comment: @Druckles any idea where to go from there?

Comment: Yes, draw it out, step by step, to understand what the method does. Use boxes to represent the items (`T`) and lines to represent the pointers (`.next`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `<=` to `>=`:

```
public void add(T item, int priority) throws QueueOverflowException {    
    SortedLinkedListNode<T> current = head;
    SortedLinkedListNode<T> previous = new SortedLinkedListNode<T>(); 
    SortedLinkedListNode<T> newNode = new SortedLinkedListNode<T>(); 
    newNode.priority = priority;
    newNode.data = item; 
    previous =null;

    while (current != null && current.priority >= priority) {
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }

    if (previous == null) {
        newNode.next = current;
        first = newNode;
    } else {
        newNode.next = current;
        previous.next = newNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: where do the variables `first` and `head` come from?

Comment: They are described outside of the void. I think the logic is just incorrect on how the nodes are added. It shouldn't be the same as adding the node in ascending order?

Comment: The logic isn't the same. By changing the comparison, you change the point at which the function stops looking for where to put the next one.

Comment: `while (current != null)
  {
   if(current.priority > priority)
   {   previous = current; 
    current = current.next;
   }
   else {
    previous.next = current;
    current = current.next;
   }
     

  }
 

 if (previous == null) {
        newNode.next = current;
        first = newNode;
    } 

    else {
        newNode.next = current;
        previous.next = newNode;
    }   
   }
   }
` would it look something like that or I am completely off? @Druckles